# Change How Pandas Displays nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I remember correctly, in Stata `nan` are displayed as `.`. Displaying them as such is particularly helpful if you have a lot of missing values as it draws emphasis to the filled values rather than the reverse. Is there any option in Pandas for an alternative `nan` display?

```py
x = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5)) * 100).round()
x[x>10] = np.nan
x
    0       1       2       3       4
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     5.0
2   NaN     NaN     NaN     0.0     NaN
3   1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     9.0
4   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN

# Preferably a parameter that set this functionality:
x.fillna('.')
    0   1   2   3   4
0   .   .   .   .   .
1   .   .   .   1   5
2   .   .   .   0   .
3   1   .   .   .   9
4   .   .   .   .   .
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps a `Styler` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Answer (score 10):

You can use Pandas styling, as shown [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Missing-values)

```
df.style.set_na_rep(".")
```

Comment: Sorry, taking away my accepted "check" due to this not having the functionality that I was looking for.

Comment: @FrancisSmart No problem. Could you explain what functionality it is exactly that you are looking for? Using ```set_na_rep()``` and and ```fillna()``` are both perfectly acceptable ways to replace the NaN default so I don't quite understand.

Comment: sure. I was looking for some parameter either global to pandas options or object specific to a DataFrame that allowed the DataFrame to be displayed consistently matching that format. `styles` are cool but don't implement the ongoing interactive display I was hoping for. Operationally `df.style.set_na_rep(".")` is more wordy than `df.fillna('.')` when what I really want is just `df`.